# Create specific country map using shape file in OBIEE12c - Map view not show value/measure in OBIEE 12c Dashboard

Tags: oracle, shapefile, obiee, oracle-map-viewer

I want to create Indonesian map in obiee 12c, I have been following this tutorial https://www.justanalytics.com/blog/spatial-2 to import Indonesia shape file in Oracle Mapbuilder for spatial data. After that I also followed this tutorial http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/bi/bi1116/obiee_maps/obiee_maps.html, the steps in Mapbuilder are :

1. create state_theme & city_theme from Indonesia province geometry table,
2. create indonesia_basemap which consist of those Indonesian state_theme & city_theme,
3. create indonesia_tileLayer from that indonesia_basemap then I define tile bounds & zoom level,
4. create layers & background maps in Administration -> manage map data.
5. Configure tileLayer & datasource in mapviewer also layer key & BI Key column

But when the map show, it isn't showing the value or measure on dashboard, I have tried the same steps in obiiee 11g and it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by add mds config on mapviewer xml configuration. based on this video https://youtu.be/Ebl_mjUC6hI . Thanks.